# Passing IDataReader to inherited classes not closing connections ExecuteDataReaderAsync in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sqldatareader

I am having a serious problem and I am not sure how to fix it. I have multiple libraries pointing to a main data provider C# library. I set it up to perform asynchronous calls to ExecuteDataReaderAsync. However, the SQL connections are not closing as expected so I'm getting SQL connection pool errors.

I tried wrapping the SqlConnection in a using however the IDataReader does not get returned since it's outside the scope of the using.

Here is my main data provider method (DataProvider.cs)

```
public virtual async Task<SqlDataReader> ExecuteDataReaderAsync(string StoredProcedureName, params object[] Parameters)
        {
            InitDatabase();

            var connection = new SqlConnection(databaseControllers[connectionStringName].ConnectionString);


            var cmd = new SqlCommand()
            {
                Connection = connection,
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                CommandText = dbPrefixName + StoredProcedureName,
            };
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
            if (cmd.Parameters.Count - 1 > Parameters.Count())
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The number of parameters provided does not match the number of parameters in the stored procedure. There are " + Parameters.Count().ToString() + " parameters provided, however the stored procedure requires " + cmd.Parameters.Count.ToString() + " parameters.");

            for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Count(); i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters[i + 1].Value = Parameters[i];
            }


            var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            return reader;

        }
```

Here is an example of the implementation in an inherited class:

```
 internal async Task<List<Models.PermitAssociatedApplication>> RemoveAssociatedApplication(int PermitApplicationId)
        {
            List<Models.PermitAssociatedApplication> temp = new List<Models.PermitAssociatedApplication>();
            using (IDataReader reader = await ExecuteDataReaderAsync("AssociatedApplications_RemoveApplication", PermitApplicationId))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    temp.Add(FillAssociatedApplication(reader));
            }
            return temp;
        }
```

Any thoughts how I can fix this? Our application is set to go live in a matter of days.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `Close()` method on the datareader and that will close the connection. Otherwise it will stay open. Since you have this `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`, calling `Close()` on the datareader will close the underlying connection.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same goal? I have this in hundreds of locations.

Comment: It took a lot of searching but got everything updated and it is running beautifully, even with a connection pool size of 2 for testing. Thank you so much!